# Telegram bot doesn't respond to messages in channel?

Tags: php, channel, telegram-bot

I have created a channel in telegram and I added a bot as an administrator of the channel. When I send a message to channel the bot doesn't answer, why?

I can send a message with **/sendmessage**

https://api.telegram.org/bot[key]/sendmessage?chat_id=@MyChannelID&text=This text is from bot to channel.

I am using: https://github.com/Eleirbag89/TelegramBotPHP

And this is a simple test code for bot:

```
 <?php 

include 'connection.php';
include("Telegram.php");
define('bot_id', '227493781:AAE2x0l3BRrjGN3S8wMVo9zOTYbbwr8');
$telegram = new Telegram(bot_id);

$text = $telegram->Text();
$chat_id = $telegram->ChatID();

if ($text == "call") {
    $content = array('chat_id' => $chat_id, 'text' => "This is test     message!!!");
    $telegram->sendMessage($content);   
 }

?>
```

Comment: Did you set `/setprivacy` in the `@BotFather`?

Comment: yes, I enabled privacy, and the bot is one of the admins of the channel. The bot is responding in group chat, but in channel it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Bots can't receive messages in Channels, you can only send messages.

Update:
Bots can receive updates from channels now, If they are added as administrator

Answer (score 0):

try logging the messages when the are received, then see the response...

i just checked and im able to have the bot respond to a command send in the channel (the bot is an admin in the channel)

make sure you are sending it to the right channel, if you use the channel id, it should be something like `-1001254460186` and if you use the channel username it should start with a `@`...

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not a complete answer to the original question, which is over two years old. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for guidance.

Comment: thanks, ill keep the answer guide in mind, also since i saw this question on the side in the related questions section, should i not try to answer questions that are "old"

Answer (score 0):

You can get the info of the last message in chanell with :

`messageId = message[-1].message_id`

`messageText = message[-1].text`

All you want ;)